# java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING

Tags: memcached, spymemcached

Looks like lot of timeout or waiting for connections.
Can any one help to fix it ?

```
"DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1@1359" prio=5 tid=0x1fb nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:198)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1011)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.tryAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1303)
      at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:253)
      at net.spy.memcached.internal.OperationFuture.get(OperationFuture.java:59)
      at net.spy.memcached.internal.GetFuture.get(GetFuture.java:37)
      at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient.get(MemcachedClient.java:1135)
```

Comment: Please post the version of spymemcached you are using and your code. It is impossible to known what is going on from just a stack trace.